# Convert base64 to readable string

Tags: sql-server, hive, hiveql

I have a table having nvarchar column in SQL server 2016 that I want to store in hive. The nvarchar column can have non-ASCII characters. The data from SQL server is extracted in a file with the nvarchar column converted to base64 coded string. I tried the following to convert the base64 back to readable string:

```
select decode(unbase64(BASE64STR),'UTF-8');
```

It failed with the following error:

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling
>   statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong
>   arguments ''UTF-8'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

The following code is able to propertly decode BASE64 coded string

```
select decode(unbase64(BASE64STR),'UTF-16LE');
```

Is it safe to use UTF-16LE to decode the string from nvarchar type column? Will this work with any data stored in the column? Is there another way to achieve this ETL functionality from SQL Server to Hive for nvarchar type data?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the functions for working with base64 that we have in SDU Tools (free). They go to/from varbinary but might work ok with strings cast to/from that. At the very least, the code should give you a good start. They are at: http://sdutools.sqldownunder.com